# Writing sflow data from port 6343 into csv file in Scientific Linux using C Programming

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am trying to write the `sflow` data from the port `6343` into a `csv` file. The code compiles but the data packets are not stored in the file. The follow code was used by me. I referenced [this code](http://www.binarytides.com/packet-sniffer-code-c-linux/) with modifications for capturing only `UDP` packets along with `IP` header and `UDP` header information and also creating `socket` for specific port.

```
 #include<stdio.h> //For standard things
 #include<stdlib.h>    //malloc
 #include<string.h>    //memset
 #include<netinet/ip_icmp.h>   //Provides declarations for icmp header
 #include<netinet/udp.h>   //Provides declarations for udp header
 #include<netinet/tcp.h>   //Provides declarations for tcp header
 #include<netinet/ip.h>    //Provides declarations for ip header
 #include<netinet/if_ether.h>  //For ETH_P_ALL
 #include<net/ethernet.h>  //For ether_header
 #include<sys/socket.h>
 #include<arpa/inet.h>
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #define PORT 6343

void ProcessPacket(unsigned char* , int);
void print_ip_header(unsigned char* , int);
void print_udp_packet(unsigned char * , int);
void PrintData (unsigned char* , int);

int sock;
FILE *logfile;
int udp=0,total=0,i,j;
struct sockaddr_in source,dest;

int main()
{
    int saddr_size , data_size;
    int yes=1;
    struct sockaddr saddr;
    struct in_addr in;
    struct sockaddr_in myaddr;

    unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(65536); //Its Big!

    logfile=fopen("log.csv","w");
    if(logfile==NULL) printf("Unable to create file.");
    printf("Starting...\n");

     myaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
     myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
     myaddr.sin_port=htons(6343);     

     sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
     if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(yes)) == -1) 
     {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(1);
     }
     if(sock<0)
     {
         printf("failed to create socket");
         return 1;
      }

     if(bind(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&myaddr,sizeof(myaddr))<0)
     {
         printf("binding failed");
         return 1;
     }

     listen(sock,5);
     while(1)
     {
        saddr_size = sizeof saddr;
        //Receive a packet
        data_size = recvfrom(sock , buffer , 65536 , 0 , &saddr , &saddr_size);
        if(data_size <0 )
        {
            printf("Recvfrom error , failed to get packets\n");
            return 1;
        }
     //Now process the packet
     ProcessPacket(buffer , data_size);
     }
    close(sock);
    printf("Finished");
    return 0;
}

void ProcessPacket(unsigned char* buffer, int size)
{
    //Get the IP Header part of this packet
    struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr*)buffer;
    ++total;
    switch (iph->protocol) //Check the Protocol and do accordingly...
    {

        case 17: //UDP Protocol
            ++udp;
            print_udp_packet(buffer , size);
            break;
    }

    printf("UDP : %d   Total : %d\r",udp,total);
}

void print_ip_header(unsigned char* Buffer, int Size)
{
    unsigned short iphdrlen;

    struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)Buffer;
    iphdrlen =iph->ihl*4;

    memset(&source, 0, sizeof(source));
    source.sin_addr.s_addr = iph->saddr;

    memset(&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));
    dest.sin_addr.s_addr = iph->daddr;

    fprintf(logfile,"\n");
    fprintf(logfile,"IP Header\n");
    fprintf(logfile,"   |-IP Version        : %d\n",(unsigned int)iph->version);
    fprintf(logfile,"   |-IP Header Length  : %d DWORDS or %d Bytes\n",(unsigned int)iph->ihl,((unsigned int)(iph->ihl))*4);
    fprintf(logfile,"   |-Type Of Service   : %d\n",(unsigned int)iph->tos);
    fprintf(logfile,"   |-IP Total Length   : %d  Bytes(Size of Packet)\n",ntohs(iph->tot_len));
    fprintf(logfile,"   |-Identification    : %d\n",ntohs(iph->id));
    //fprintf(logfile,"   |-Reserved ZERO Field   : %d\n",(unsigned int)iphdr->ip_reserved_zero);
    //fprintf(logfile,"   |-Dont Fragment Field   : %d\n",(unsigned int)iphdr->ip_dont_fragment);
    //fprintf(logfile,"   |-More Fragment Field   : %d\n",(unsigned int)iphdr->ip_more_fragment);
    fprintf(logfile,"   |-TTL      : %d\n",(unsigned int)iph->ttl);
    fprintf(logfile,"   |-Protocol : %d\n",(unsigned int)iph->protocol);
    fprintf(logfile,"   |-Checksum : %d\n",ntohs(iph->check));
    fprintf(logfile,"   |-Source IP        : %s\n",inet_ntoa(source.sin_addr));
    fprintf(logfile,"   |-Destination IP   : %s\n",inet_ntoa(dest.sin_addr));
}

void print_udp_packet(unsigned char *Buffer , int Size)
{

    unsigned short iphdrlen;

    struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)Buffer;
    iphdrlen = iph->ihl*4;

    struct udphdr *udph = (struct udphdr*)(Buffer + iphdrlen);

    fprintf(logfile,"\n\n***********************UDP Packet*************************\n");

    print_ip_header(Buffer,Size);           

    fprintf(logfile,"\nUDP Header\n");
    fprintf(logfile,"   |-Source Port      : %d\n" , ntohs(udph->source));
    fprintf(logfile,"   |-Destination Port : %d\n" , ntohs(udph->dest));
    fprintf(logfile,"   |-UDP Length       : %d\n" , ntohs(udph->len));
    fprintf(logfile,"   |-UDP Checksum     : %d\n" , ntohs(udph->check));

    fprintf(logfile,"\n");
    fprintf(logfile,"IP Header\n");
    PrintData(Buffer , iphdrlen);

    fprintf(logfile,"UDP Header\n");
    PrintData(Buffer+iphdrlen , sizeof udph);

    fprintf(logfile,"Data Payload\n");  
    PrintData(Buffer + iphdrlen + sizeof udph ,( Size - sizeof udph - iph->ihl * 4 ));

    fprintf(logfile,"\n###########################################################");
}

void PrintData (unsigned char* data , int Size)
{

    for(i=0 ; i < Size ; i++)
    {
        if( i!=0 && i%16==0)   //if one line of hex printing is complete...
        {
            fprintf(logfile,"         ");
            for(j=i-16 ; j<i ; j++)
            {
                if(data[j]>=32 && data[j]<=128)
                    fprintf(logfile,"%c",(unsigned char)data[j]); //if its a number or alphabet

                else fprintf(logfile,"."); //otherwise print a dot
            }
            fprintf(logfile,"\n");
        } 

        if(i%16==0) fprintf(logfile,"   ");
            fprintf(logfile," %02X",(unsigned int)data[i]);

        if( i==Size-1)  //print the last spaces
        {
            for(j=0;j<15-i%16;j++) fprintf(logfile,"   "); //extra spaces

            fprintf(logfile,"         ");

            for(j=i-i%16 ; j<=i ; j++)
            {
                if(data[j]>=32 && data[j]<=128) fprintf(logfile,"%c",(unsigned char)data[j]);
                else fprintf(logfile,".");
            }
            fprintf(logfile,"\n");
        }
    }
}
```

can you please advise me what is wrong in the code ?

Answer (score 0):

The original packet sniffing code creates a raw socket

```
sock_raw = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_RAW , IPPROTO_TCP);
```

Raw sockets gets data including IP headers. But your program creates the UDP socket

```
sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
```

The UDP sockets and TCP sockets provides data without IP, UDP and TCP headers. That means the buffer contains data only.

Edited - to explain details:

Yes, that is consequence of the network protocol stack design. Each layer has specific tasks.

The simplified processing looks like:

- A packet is received and process in the IP layer. The IP layer removes IP header and move the packet up to the UDP layer.
- The UDP layer removes the UDP header and copy data to the buffer. Then kernel wakes up the `recvfrom`  call.

When you use the UDP socket then you cannot get information from IP header because it is already removed. When you use the raw socket then you cannot filter packet by ports because the port is not known before processing in IP and UDP layers.

The functionality you miss looks reasonable at the first look but you have to consider what to do when

- A non IPv4 packet is received with your port.
- IPv4 fragment is received that belongs to packet for the port you want.
- UDP packet is encapsulated in IPsec or any other protocol.
- ...

So you have to acquiesce the fact that there are only two options. Either use the comfort that UDP socket provides but you will not see the details of lower protocols or use the raw socket and then do more work and implement port filtering in your application.

Comment: But using raw socket means listening to all ports isn't?? But in my case I want to listen to data from port 6343. For that reason I removed the raw socket function and replaced with normal UDP socket creation.

Comment: It's nonsence. See Step 4. in [Programming with UDP sockets](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/417/notes/sockets/udp.html). There is address stored in your `saddr` structure.

Comment: May be it is a nonsense. Nevertheless when you look at the [Programming with UDP sockets](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/417/notes/sockets/udp.html) then you can see that `recfrom` provides buffer and sockaddr_in. It neither provides UDP nor IP header. The IP address and port  are passed up together with the application data. But the question was about IP/UDP header. It was not about source IP/port.

Comment: thank you for your comments guys.. I have a question, is it possible to capture the UDP packets from port 6343 directly into a postgresql database? can you please help with the source for it ? I have to use C programming to implement this concept in scientific Linux machine.

Comment: Everything is possible but it is necessary to know what is required.Do you really need to store IP header as well? Note there in no 1 : 1 relation between UDP datagrams and IP packets. UDP datagram may be fragmented, UDP datagram may be delivered by other means than IPv4. So what is supposed to be in the database?

Comment: The database should contain the sflow data which is UDP packets. when I searched in online for the sflow data structure, I saw the following fields:  sflow entry, agent address, inputPort, outputPort, src_MAC,  dst_MAC,  ethernet_type, in_vlan,  out_vlan, src_IP, dst_IP,
IP_protocol,  ip_tos, ip_ttl, udp_src_port OR tcp_src_port OR icmp_type,udp_dst_port OR tcp_dst_port OR icmp_code, tcp_flags, packet_size, IP_size and sampling_rate. These fields have to be stored directly into the postgresql database.